# Probability of rolling dice

Tags: probability

if you roll a single die 6 times, what is the probability of getting at least 2 sixes?

I seem to have tried everything I know how to do and I'm still not getting the right answer.

Comment: It's good to know that you've tried something, but please include what you've tried in your post so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What is the probability you get one six? zero sixes?

Answer (score 1):

****Hint :**

$ P(x\ge 2) = 1 - P(x \leq 1) = 1 - P(x= 1) - P(x=0) $**